# redirect to subdirectory and always get 404 not found in Slim php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, slim

I want make two slim app, one for api calling and another one for website users.
I put my main php file into 'src' directory, and the structure is as below:

```
/  
---.htaccess  
---/src(here are files)  
-----.htaccess  
-----index.php(Slim)  
-----/Controllers  
-----/Views  
-----/Models  
-----/api  
-------.htaccess  
-------index.php(Slim)  
---/public  
-----/js  
-----/css  
-----/fonts
```

i want to make my url from this:
`http://localhost/project/src/api/foo`
to
`http://locahost/project/api/foo`

I don't know how to write the first `.htaccess`(root) 
i try to redirect to subdir like this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^src/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^ src/ [QSA,L]
```

but it always returns 404 Not found by Slim. i thought it did redirect to subdir but the slim router wont get correct url, am i right?

and others looks like this:(I just copy the documentation from SlimFramework)

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA]
```

any ideas would help me a lot! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule in your `/project/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteCond  !/src/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ src/$1 [L]
```

Make sure this is your first rule.

Comment: still not working...the url will redirect like this `src/index.php/project/hello/`, and i think the slim only accept like this `src/index.php/hello/`

Comment: See updated code make sure it is in `/project/.htaccess` not in `DocumentRoot`

Comment: yes, i put it into /project/ and type http://localhost/project/hello/ in the browser, the slim still show 404 not found.

Comment: Try with `R` flag for testing: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ src/$1 [L,R]`

Comment: it still not working. i give up! at last i use `virtual host` instead.

Comment: This is one of the **simplest rule** I have written. So probably either .htaccess OR mod_rewrite isn't enabled for you.

Comment: thanks a lot anyway! still helpful~ i think, next time i should create a better structure or dig into slimframework to figure out the route principle